# Problem with the Android List View Implementation from Database Records

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Thanks a lot for the previous answered questions.Now, I am developing an application having the database implementation. I used the database queries to retrieve the data from Database but unable to display the retrieved data records as a list of an activity. Please suggest me with the sample code.

Comment: You want some simple listview(for example you only want the name of you item in the list) or customized list view(you want the name, date of insertion, other details)?

Comment: I want to implement a customized list View(including the queried database records, date of list implemented).

Comment: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html quite simple to understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)u need to add data to arraylist and set the arryalistobject to setlistadapter.2)
 ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ",null);

```
           if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("KEY_ID"));
                    // System.out.println("this is first activity"+firstName);
                    String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("First_Name"));
                    String lastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Last_Name"));
                        //System.out.println("this is first activity====age"+age);
                        results.add("" + firstName + ",lastName: " + lastName);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
```